# How to fix an error "FAIL : ValueError: Element locator" in AppiumLibrary with Robotframework?

Tags: automation, appium, robotframework, appium-android

I am working with `AppiumLibrary` with `Robotframwork` and have got an error `FAIL : ValueError: Element locator '//*[@text="STG"]' did not match any elements`.

```
Test Case1
| FAIL |
ValueError: Element locator '//*[@text="STG"]' did not match any elements.
```

This is the test case:

```
**Settings**: Library AppiumLibrary

**Test Cases**: Test Case1 

    Open Application    http://localhost:4723/wd/hub  
    platformName=Android  deviceName=ZY22452GQX    
    app=/home/keval/Desktop/extra/app-rheem-qa(1).apk    
    appPackage=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa    
    appActivity=com.econet.ui.MainActivity

    Click Element    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/
    activity_login_logo_image_view
    Click Element    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/
    activity_login_logo_image_view
    Click Element    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/
    activity_login_logo_image_view
    Click Text    text=STG    exact_match=False
    Click Element    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/menu_save
    Input Text    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/
    login_email_text    text=deepali.gill@volansystech.com
    Input Password    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/
    login_password_text    text=kalpesh@2017
    Click Element    id=com.rheem.econetconsumerandroid.qa:id/login_button
```

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: You don't appear to be waiting for the screen to finish rendering. If you add a wait or a sleep before the line that causes the error, does the error go away?

Answer (score 0):

The locator looks to be valid. Looks like you are doing login, so maybe need to wait for element to appear on UI:

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element  //*[@text="STG"]
```

[More details](http://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html)